# RFC 1123 date representation with Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, browser-cache, rfc1123

We're using jetty as front end http server, with cache policies. I would like to be clear on the requirements:

1. Is the quoted below required?
2. How should I implement this in Java?

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html says:

> HTTP/1.1 requires origin servers to
>   send a Date header, if possible, with
>   every response, giving the time at
>   which the response was generated (see
>   section 14.18). We use the term
>   "date_value" to denote the value of
>   the Date header, in a form appropriate
>   for arithmetic operations.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.18:

> The Date general-header field
>   represents the date and time at which
>   the message was originated, having the
>   same semantics as orig-date in RFC
>   822. The field value is an HTTP-date, as described in section 3.3.1; it MUST
>   be sent in RFC 1123 [8]-date format.

Does jetty contains built in support for Date fields or should I be adding this by myself? Any efficient method to generate this field?

Thank you,
Maxim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server` class has a boolean `sendDateHeader` property that enables this. It really should be done by default, but it isn't.

You can either set that programmatically, or usins a `<Set>` element in `jetty.xml`